# WSO2 APIM strips JSON payload when sending POST to Web API ODATA v4

Tags: json, api, rest, wso2, odata

I have a Web API OData v4 web service POST method that works just fine when called directly from a unit test using HTTPWebRequest. I used Swashbuckle to generate Swagger docs from the Web API service and published this to the WSO2 APIM (I have tried this with v1.10.0 and v2.0 BETA).

When I make the exact same requests through the APIM, the JSON content of most requests, (the first couple of requests usually go through), is apparently not being serialized correctly, and the Web API service receives a null content. I am guessing that there is a serialization error, then the APIM suspends the endpoint and I start getting null request bodies.

There are no errors in the APIM logs. I wonder if the APIM is trying to serialize the JSON content as XML, like it does in the ESB? I wonder if I may have to move on without WSO2. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: It may be hard for readers to visualise the problem you describe. Are you able to capture the request/response that you think is being serialised incorrectly? Can we see your request/response headers too?

Comment: Application serialization is not an issue. The request is correct when it gets to the APIM, (I have confirmed with Fiddler), then something happens within the APIM server that is not visible to me, hence the question. The APIM is supposed to act as a pass-through proxy, without message mediation. However, when the request arrives at the source Web API server, the payload is no longer there. I know that in the WSO2 ESB server, JSON requests are converted to XML prior to mediation as a default. My concern is that something similar is happening within the APIM because of shared Carbon heritage.

Comment: This is way outside of my domain knowledge, but can you show any of your investigations in the question? Also, do any of these components under your control have extended/verbose logging modes that could be enabled for a short time?

Comment: I believe that I have resolved this, although without an adequate explanation. I was doing code (C#) cleanup on the client and modified the use of explicit Close() on the request and response streams, and replaced it with using statements. Worked like a charm. I guess .NET and Java were not playing well together.

Comment: OK, excellent news! Would you be able to post an answer of sorts, or is it best closed as "can no longer be reproduced"?